# How to address generic types by accessing them via Assembly?

Tags: c#, c++, generics, assemblies, native

I'm working with a hosted CLR to access a .NET-Assembly. This assembly contains generic types as:

```
MyGenericClass<MyClass>  // C# notation
```

Where spAssembly is my hosted and loaded assembly, I need to get this type via string (bstrClassName).

```
spAssembly->GetType_2(bstrClassName, &spType);  // C++-Access via hosted Assembly
```

So now I need to know how to format the classname-string. For regular classes i use something like

```
MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.MyClass  // Full adressing for the query.
```

I guess I have to address it like this:

```
MyNamespace.MyGenericClass<MyNamespace.MySubNamespace.MyClass>
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea? Maybe a wrong syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics in .Net work different than C++ templates. You have to get the generic type first and then generate a concrete type from it. So you first have to get `MyGenericClass` and use [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) passing `MyClass` as parameter.

Comment: Thank you, very useful answer. Never thougt about that. :)

Comment: Okay one question is left. In which header is MakeGenericType defined?

Comment: No idea. I never hosted the CLR. It's a member of System.Type which is part of System.dll as far as I know. Don't know if that's of any help.

Comment: Nope it should be a part of mscorlib.dll. But it isn't defined in the header. So maybe it is an other library. *searching*